# change a field's value with vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to change a date in a specific table to today's date by clicking a button in a related form.  So all the button does is changing the date in a certain field in my DB. Is there a simple way to do this with VBA?

*Update

Well I wrote this in my VBA code:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Machines SET LastMaintenance = Date() WHERE MachineID = MachineID.Value"
```

With "`Machines`" being my table, "`LastMaintenance`" the column containing the date that has to be changed into today's date, "`MachineID`" the name of the record and "`MachineID.Value`" the name of the textbox bound to that same record.

When I click the button I get this error:

> "Not enough parameters. 1 expected."

Comment: In regards to your edit, you want to take the VBA code out of the SQL string i.e. `CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Machines SET LastMaintenance = '" & Date() & "' WHERE MachineID = " & MachineID.Value`

Answer (score 5):

When performing an update query, you'll want to be cognizant of the datatype for each field, as you will have to present it differently in your code.  Also, you will need to break up your string text when inserting a variable.  In your current state, it's looking for a MachineID field with 'MachineID.value' as its contents.  Try this:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Machines SET LastMaintenance = Date() WHERE MachineID = " & MachineID.Value
```

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward way is to run a UPDATE query.

```
CurrentDB.Execute "UPDATE someTable SET someDate = Date() WHERE stuff = 47"
```

Answer (score 1):

If

> a button in a related form

means a form bound to that table displaying the record you wish to update, use the *OnClick* event of the button:

```
Private Sub NameOfYourButton_Click()

    Me![NameOfYourDateField].Value = Date
    ' Optionally, save the record at once:
    Me.Dirty = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

An `UPDATE` command is dangerous because you are making a change to the database assuming sane inputs. I would recommend using parameterized VBA code to avoid both SQL injection and throw an error in VBA for malformed inputs.

This example uses a static string to load your recordset, then it clearly states that the unverified input is only used in a Find command. Then it only acts if a matching record is found. This is a safer operation, albeit more verbose. It's also debuggable in VBA where the SQL UPDATE command is a kind of black box.

```
With CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Machines", dbOpenDynaset)
    .FindFirst "[MachineID]=" & CLng(MachineID.Value)
    If .NoMatch Then
        Debug.Print "ID not found: " & MachineID.Value
    Else
        .Edit
        .Fields.Item("LastMaintenance").Value = Date()
        .Update
    End If

    .Close
End With
```